# How to run async function in a new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I want to run `async def orderbook()` function in new thread but the code not working ,the code stop at `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()` in `orderbook_callback()`
I don't understand why, the `orderbook_callback()` work fine ouside thread but doesn't work in new thread

```
import asyncio
import json
import threading
import websockets.client
import websockets.exceptions



ws_url = "wss://phemex.com/ws/"
sub_orderbook = {"id": 1234, "method": "orderbook.subscribe", "params": ["BTCUSD"]}


async def orderbook():
    while True:
        try:
            async for websocket in websockets.client.connect(ws_url, close_timeout=0.001):
                try:
                   
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps(sub_orderbook))
                    while True:
                        msg = await websocket.recv()
                        print(msg)
                        obj = json.loads(msg)
                        if isinstance(obj, dict) and obj.get('event') == 'ping':
                            await websocket.send(json.dumps({'event': 'pong'}))
                
                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as cc:
                    logger.warning(f'Connection at {ws_url} closed: {cc}')
                    continue
        except Exception:
            logger.warning(f'Restarting after unexpected exception:', exc_info=True)

def orderbook_callback():
    print("Hi")
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    print("bye")
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(orderbook())
    loop.close()

# orderbook_callback()

_thread = threading.Thread(target=orderbook_callback, daemon=True)
_thread.start()
```

Comment: An event loop can be run per process. You could use `multiprocessing`, and then create an event loop in a process worker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python-worker` [link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/)

```
import asyncio
import json
import threading
import websockets.client
import websockets.exceptions
from worker import async_worker



ws_url = "wss://phemex.com/ws/"
sub_orderbook = {"id": 1234, "method": "orderbook.subscribe", "params": ["BTCUSD"]}

@async_worker
async def orderbook():
    while True:
        try:
            async for websocket in websockets.client.connect(ws_url, close_timeout=0.001):
                try:
                   
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps(sub_orderbook))
                    while True:
                        msg = await websocket.recv()
                        print(msg)
                        obj = json.loads(msg)
                        if isinstance(obj, dict) and obj.get('event') == 'ping':
                            await websocket.send(json.dumps({'event': 'pong'}))
                
                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as cc:
                    logger.warning(f'Connection at {ws_url} closed: {cc}')
                    continue
        except Exception:
            logger.warning(f'Restarting after unexpected exception:', exc_info=True)


asyncio.run(orderbook())

print("run in thread success")
```

the last line will be executed bcs your `async` function already executed as a worker