# Run async function in a new thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I would like to run an async defined function in a separate thread using the Python `asyncio` library. I am on Python 3.11.

I know that I can use `asyncio.to_thread` to run regular functions in a separate thread, and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316863/is-asyncio-to-thread-method-different-to-threadpoolexecutor) I know it does this by using `loop.run_in_executor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` under the hood. However, `asyncio.to_thread` accepts regular functions, and I would like to do this on an async function instead. Meaning, that I want to take an async function and return a coroutine that I can run as a task using `asyncio.create_task`, where that task is executed on a separate thread. As far as I understand `asyncio.create_task` runs async functions concurrently, but not necessarily in a separate thread.

How can I do this with only the `asyncio` library? I would not like to run it using the regular `threading` library due to some restrictions I have with other libraries I am using.

I took a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524878/how-to-run-async-function-in-a-new-thread) and the answer does not stick to the stl. And in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151031/start-an-async-function-inside-a-new-thread) the answer does not pertain to my particular question.

Comment: If you are dealing with other libraries and need to make them compatible with each other, you can implement a proxy pattern to make two different interfaces compatible with each other.